# File Masking in delphi

Tags: delphi, mask

I am trying to find all files that have the extenstion .cbr or .cbz

If i set my mask to *.cb?

it finds *.cbproj files.  How can i set the mask to only find .cbr and .cbz files?

here is code i am using.

I have two edit boxes EDIT1 is the location to search, EDIT2 is where i put my mask. A listbox to show what it found and a Search button.

```
edit1 := c:\
edit2 := mask (*.cb?)
```

space

```
    procedure TFAutoSearch.FileSearch(const PathName, FileName : string; const InDir : boolean);
var Rec  : TSearchRec;
    Path : string;
begin
Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(PathName);
if FindFirst(Path + FileName, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
 try
   repeat
     ListBox1.Items.Add(Path + Rec.Name);
   until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
 finally
   FindClose(Rec);
 end;

If not InDir then Exit;

if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
 try
   repeat
    if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  and (Rec.Name<>'.') and (Rec.Name<>'..') then
     FileSearch(Path + Rec.Name, FileName, True);
   until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
 finally
   FindClose(Rec);
 end;
end; //procedure FileSearch



procedure TFAutoSearch.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileSearch(Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, CheckBox1.State in [cbChecked]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: ? - cannot find any mask in your code.

Comment: my mask is Edit2.text   Which is *.cb?

Comment: @GlenMorse have you tried with mask "STAR.cbr;STAR.cbz"?

Comment: Have not. Did not know you could do that. I'll try

Comment: @GlenMorse replace STAR with it's corresponding symbol, SO is considering it as a formatting...

Comment: Why not just use SysUtils.ExtractFileExt(FullFileName : string ) : string;
Function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `ExtractFileExt` against the current filename and check to see if it matches either of your desired extensions.

Here's a fully-rewritten version of your `FileSearch` routine which does exactly what you're trying to do (according to your question, anyway):

```
procedure TFAutoSearch.FileSearch(const ARoot: String);
var
  LExt, LRoot: String;
  LRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  LRoot := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ARoot);
  if FindFirst(LRoot + '*.*', faAnyFile, LRec) = 0 then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (LRec.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) and (LRec.Name <> '.') and (LRec.Name <> '..') then
          FileSearch(LRoot + LRec.Name)
        else
        begin
          LExt := UpperCase(ExtractFileExt(LRoot + LRec.Name));
          if (LExt = '.CBR') or (LExt = '.CBZ') then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(LRoot + LRec.Name);
        end;
      until (FindNext(LRec) <> 0);
    finally
      FindClose(LRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

While the other answer suggesting the use of multiple extensions as a mask `*.cbr;*.cbz` should (in principal anyway) work, I've noted through bitter experience that the `FindFirst` and `FindNext` methods in Delphi tend not to accept multiple extensions in a mask!

The code I've provided should work just fine for your needs, so enjoy!

**UPDATED**: To allow the use of multiple extensions in a Mask dynamically at runtime (as indicated by the OP's first comment to this answer).

What we're going to do is take a `String` from your `TEdit` control (this `String` is one or more File Extensions as you would expect), "Explode" the `String` into an `Array`, and match each file against each Extension in the `Array`.

Sounds more complicated than it is:

```
type
  TStringArray = Array of String; // String Dynamic Array type...

// Now let's provide a "Mask Container" inside the containing class...
  TFAutoSearch = class(TForm)
    // Normal stuff in here
  private
    FMask: TStringArray; // Our "Mask Container"
  end;
```

This code will populate `FMask` with each individual mask extension separated by a `;` such as `.CBR;.CBZ`.

Note this method will not accept Wildcard characters or any other Regex magic, but you can modify it as you require!

```
procedure TFAutoSearch.ExplodeMask(const AValue: String);
var
  LTempVal: String;
  I, LPos: Integer;
begin
  LTempVal := AValue;
  I := 0;
  while Length(LTempVal) > 0 do
  begin
    Inc(I);
    SetLength(FMask, I);
    LPos := Pos(';', LTempVal);

    if (LPos > 0) then
    begin
      FMask[I - 1] := UpperCase(Copy(LTempVal, 0, LPos - 1));
      LTempVal := Copy(LTempVal, LPos +  1, Length(LTempVal));
    end
    else
    begin
      FMask[I - 1] := UpperCase(LTempVal);
      LTempVal := EmptyStr;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

We now need a function to determine if the nominated file matches any of the defined Extensions:

```
function TFAutoSearch.MatchMask(const AFileName: String): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  LExt: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  LExt := UpperCase(ExtractFileExt(LExt));
  for I := Low(FMask) to High(FMask) do
    if (LExt = FMask[I]) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

Now here's the modified `FileSearch` procedure:

```
procedure TFAutoSearch.FileSearch(const ARoot: String);
var
  LRoot: String;
  LRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  LRoot := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ARoot);
  if FindFirst(LRoot + '*.*', faAnyFile, LRec) = 0 then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (LRec.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) and (LRec.Name <> '.') and (LRec.Name <> '..') then
          FileSearch(LRoot + LRec.Name)
        else
        begin
          if (MatchMask(LRoot + LRec.Name)) then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(LRoot + LRec.Name);
        end;
      until (FindNext(LRec) <> 0);
    finally
      FindClose(LRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Finally, here's how you initiate your search:

```
procedure TFAutoSearch.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExplodeMask(edMask.Text);
  FileSearch(edPath.Text);
end;
```

Where `edMask` is defined in your question as `Edit2` and `edPath` is defined in your question as `Edit1`. Just remember that this method doesn't support the use of Wildcard or other Special Chars, so `edMask.Text` should be something like `.CBR;.CBZ`

If you use the Regex library for Delphi, you could easily modify this method to support all of the Expression Cases you could ever imagine!

Comment: I will award bounty here, Though i did not do it exactly like this. I wanted to keep the editbox so users could select own mask.. Just added a if edit1 = *.CB?  or *.CB*  then edit1.text := cbr/z   kind of thing.. but this answer did help me get there THanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a method to support multiple Extensions specified in a `String` by the user at runtime!

Answer (score 3):

Dorin's suggestion to replace your mask with `*.cbr;*.cbz` should work. That is, it won't match cbproj anymore. It would, however, still match cbzy or any other extension that starts with cbr or cbz. The reason for this is that FindFirst/FindNext match both the long form and the legacy short forms (8.3) of file names. So the short forms will always have truncated extensions where cbproj is shortened to cbp, and therefore matches cb?.

This is supposed to be avoidable by using FindFirstEx instead, but this requires a small rewrite of your search function and actually didn't work for me. So instead I just double checked all matches with the [MatchesMask](http://delphi.about.com/library/rtl/blrtlMatchesMask.htm) function.

Comment: It's funny that the reason FindFirstFile also matches short form is: [*16-bit programs use short names*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/20/440918.aspx).

Comment: if i put in the edit  STAR.cbr;STAR.cbz (not sure how to do code tag on comment)  it finds nothing.

Comment: Ok, I'm not actually certain that FindFirstFile accepts multiple masks at once, so you might have to do it manually as I suggest. (Which is anyways the most robust solution.)